# How to merge data from Enumerators is Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, mergesort, loops

I'am using enumerator/iteratee from Play framework
I have several enumerators that each provide sorted sequence of values. I want to write Iteratee/Enumeratee that merges values from these enumerators to provide sorted sequence of all values.
Is it a good idea to use Iteratee or should I eimplement enumeratee directly?
I know that I can zip values from enumerators and reconstruct their data stream in memory and then merge such data.

But I'am wondering if there is a way how to implement a "classic" merge sort - to "read" first value from all enumerators, then select minimal value and then let enumerator that provided it to read another value (while other enumerators are on hold). As a result I want to have enumeratee that provides resulting sorted sequence without storing all streams in memory. And I would like to follow functional style - keep everything immutable.

Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You will still need to do some insertion sorting in a standard collection in memory. Imagine this pathological case:

```
Enumerator(3, 2, 1) and Enumerator(4, -1 , -2, -3)
```

Here you cannot just take the smallest element and tack it on the end of your collection. You will have to put values at arbitrary places in the collection as you go. This is part of what makes sorting fundamentally `O(n log(n))` is that you have to know your full universe of what you have to sort in order to do it any faster than that. (Bucket sort is a linear time sorting algorithm assuming you know the distribution of the values you are trying to sort)

---

To address your question more specifically:

The enumerator/iteratee library isn't really expressive enough for your use case. If you want to merge enumerators you can use `Enumerator.interleave` and do some insertion sorting in your `Iteratee` with whatever elements come in first.

If this mechanic is important to you, you could consider using the recently released [Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala.html?_ga=1.157724478.562096145.1438263138) with which you can implement a custom `FlexiMerge` push/pull stage which will allow you to do what you seek.